# PHP PDO data does not inserting

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'keys) VALUES ('1','159')' at line 1' in C:\xampp\htdocs\***\index12.php:93 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\***\index12.php(93): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\***\index12.php on line 93





$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
for($i = 1; $i < sizeof($counts_index);$i++){
    //echo $i.": ".$counts_index[$i]."<br/>";
    $index = $counts_index[$i];
    $sql1 = "INSERT INTO asce (idn,keys) VALUES (:idn,:keys)";
    $q1 = $dbh->prepare($sql1);
    $params1 = array(
        ':idn'=>$i,
        ':keys'=> $index
    );
    $q1->execute($params1);
}
```

Comment: keys is a reserved word, surround it with backticks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Keys` is a reserved word in MySQL. Either change your column name (better solution) or update your query wrapping `keys` in backticks.

```
INSERT INTO asce (idn, `keys`...
```

Comment: Oopppssss..... Thanks!